# Customize the "list" component

Tags: aem

My requirement is to sort and display the page title of the pages based on last Published date in component present in another page. So can we customize the "List" component to add the "cq:lastReplicated"`in the orderby drop-down. Tried by adding`"cq:lastReplicated"` in the drop-down value, but its not sorting. Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `orderby` doesn't work with `cq:lastReplicated` because cq:lastReplicated is a date property, but [PageComparator](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/foundation/List.PageComparator.html) used in `/libs/foundation/src/impl/src/main/java/com/day/cq/wcm/foundation/List.java` considers only *jcr:created*, *cq:lastModified* and *cq:lastPublished* as date and the remaining would be considered as String.

Due to this, `cq:lastReplicated` would be treated as String and the comparison would result in  incorrect order.

You can try overlaying the list component under /apps and then call your custom Java class which would consider cq:lastReplicated as Date instead of String.